# Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-excel

I create excel import function and it working fine until I notice the date is not inserted properly, so I try to format the date like `Y-m-d` to store properly in MySql, but the carbon gives below error

> Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
>
> Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data

In excel I may have `d/m/Y` or `Y/m/d` so I want to format to tored in DB

My Import code

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Staff([
        'employee_no'               => $row['id'],
        'name'                      => $row['name'],
        'address'                   => $row['address'],
        'fathers_name'              => $row['father'],
        'dob'                       => $this->transformDate($row['dob']),
        'blood_group'               => $row['blood_group'],
        'phone'                     => $row['phone'],
        'password'                  => Hash::make($row['id']),
    ]);
}

public function transformDate($value, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    try {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value));
    } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value);
    }
}
```

My Staff Model

```
class Staff extends Authenticatable
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'employee_no', 'designation_id', 'fathers_name', 'dob', 'identification_mark', 'blood_group', 'phone', 'address', 'height', 'rfid_no', 'building_id', 'password',
  ];

  protected $casts = ['dob'];
}
```

What is the correct way, or do I have to approach the new `format` for `dob`

Comment: `createFromFormat()` should receive the format of the given date, not the format you want to convert to. Try changing it to `$format = 'd/m/Y'`. Then you can get the database format just by making `->toDateString()` or `->toDateTimeString()` on the Carbon object

Comment: yes, correct, you solved my problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time)` should receive the format of the given `$time`, not the format you want to convert to. Try changing it to `$format = 'd/m/Y'`, as you said to be the format you expect to get from the records.

After that, you can get the database format just by making `->toDateString()` or `->toDateTimeString()` on the Carbon object.

**See also:**

- https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/